# How to convert data into a dictionary using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have to make into a list from the output extracted from the 
**http://snowload.atcouncil.org/**

**Following Code Below,**

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import csv


executable_path = r"/usr/local/share/chromedriver"
chrome_options = Options()
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = executable_path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
cities = ['Aguila arizona','Gilbert arizona']  # city list
for i in range(len(cities)):
    driver.get("http://snowload.atcouncil.org/")
    driver.find_element_by_id('optionCoordinate_Address').click()
    driver.find_element_by_id('coordinate_address').click()
    driver.find_element_by_id('coordinate_address').send_keys(cities[i])
    print (cities[i])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="adminForm"]/fieldset/div/div[2]/button').click()
    #print driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchresult-wapper"]/div[1]/ul/li[6]/p').text
    html_list = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchresult-wapper"]/div[1]/ul')
    items = html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
    count = len(items)

    for item in items:
        if(count != 1):
            text = item.text
            print text
        count = count-1
driver.close()
```

**I will get the output after extracting the data based on my code**

```
Query Date :
September 19, 2017
Address :
Aguila arizona
Latitude :
33.9428069
Longitude :
-113.1740805
Elevation :
2170.4 Feet
Elevation Limitation: ASCE 7* Ground Snow Load
Elevation ≤ 3,000 feet: Ground Snow Load is 0 psf
Elevation > 3,000 and ≤ 4,500 feet: Ground Snow Load is 5 psf
Elevation > 4,500 and ≤ 5,400 feet: Ground Snow Load is 10 psf
```

**I want to make into a dictionary  ( My output should be like)**

```
{'Query Date' :'September 19, 2017','Address' :'Aguila arizona','Latitude' :'33.9428069','Longitude' :'-113.1740805','Elevation' :'2170.4 Feet','Elevation Limitation': 'ASCE 7* Ground Snow Load','Elevation ≤ 3,000 feet': 'Ground Snow Load is 0 psf','Elevation > 3,000 and ≤ 4,500 feet': 'Ground Snow Load is 5 psf','Elevation > 4,500 and ≤ 5,400 feet': 'Ground Snow Load is 10 psf'}
```

Comment: You are confusing `dict` and `list`. There is no literal that looks like what you wrote, there's `{'x': 'y', 'a': 'b'}` which is a dictionary literal

Comment: Oops. Sorry, I should make into a dictionary

Comment: I think you actually want a dictionary of dictionaries, and the query date is independent.

Comment: I want the output like i mentioned Buddy

Comment: So I recommend you to change the format, since it does not handle different cities as different entities.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is realizing within the loop what kind of data are dealing with - is it a key (for example `'Address'`) or a value (for example `'2170.4 Feet'`).

You can do something like this:

```
result = {}  # empty dict
key = None
for item in items:
    text = item.text
    if key is not None:
        # we've found key in the previous iteration, now it's the value
        # something like 'Aguila arizona' 
        result[key] = text
        key = None
    elif text.endswith(':'):
        # this is a line such as 'Latitude :'
        key = text[-2:]  # remove ' :' at the end
    else:
        # text is something like 'Elevation Limitation: ASCE 7* Ground Snow Load'
        key, value = text.split(': ')
        result[key] = value
```

This will not work "out of the box", and I can't test it without your data, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: will it work for my extracted data which i had already mentioned in the question.

Comment: @venkat is that a question? I cannot test the data you provided, since you did not provide the content of `items`. The answer should give you the general idea of how to approach the solution.

Answer (score -2):

1. You may Use java script Serialization object to Convert this type of Json format and you will get proper result.
2. second option is to append string by comma but it is appropriate and also it is very lengthy.